# Inserting 2 Foreign Keys in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, insert, sql-update, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have the following 3 tables. They are related:

```
CREATE TABLE [MemberDetails] 
(
    [MemberID] int identity (1000,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [MName] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [MSurname] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [MPhone] varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [MEmail] varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [MAddress] varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    [MActive] char (1) NOT NULL CHECK (MActive IN ('Y','N')) DEFAULT 'Y',
    [MUpdateDate] Date NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    [MPhoto] Image NOT NULL,
    [MDid] int NULL UNIQUE,
    [MTid] int NULL UNIQUE,

    PRIMARY KEY ([MemberID]),
    FOREIGN KEY (MDid) REFERENCES [MembershipDetails] ([MDid]) 
                ON DELETE SET NULL
                ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (MTid) REFERENCES [MarketingTarget] ([MTid]) 
                ON DELETE SET NULL
                ON UPDATE CASCADE    
);

CREATE TABLE [MarketingTarget] 
(
    [MTid] int identity (5000,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [MDOB] date NOT NULL,
    [MSex] char NOT NULL CHECK (MSex IN ('M','F')) DEFAULT 'M',

    PRIMARY KEY ([MTid]),
);

CREATE TABLE [MembershipDetails] 
(
    [MDid] int identity (2000,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [MType] varchar(10) NOT NULL CHECK (MType IN ('Monthly', 'Quaterly', 'Yearly')) DEFAULT 'Monthly',
    [JoinDate] Date NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    [ExpiryDate] Date NULL,
    [MsUpdateDate] Date DEFAULT GETDATE(),

    PRIMARY KEY ([MDid])
 );
```

I would like to know if it's possible to insert the FKs automatically into the MemberDetails table from the other two tables? I am trying to write the Stored Procedures.

I was checking the `Scope_Identity` which can get the last identity generated but I am not sure how to use it properly.

Any suggestions would be much appreciate it.

Comment: You'll want to create an insert trigger - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. Example C in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example (table has been shortened): Since both IDENTITY values are required, I'd save them into a variable and then insert together into MemberDetail.
I would recommend to have a transaction for this operation. And have a look at TRY..CATCH. Depending on your situation you might want to check XACT_STATE().

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

and there are examples using a trigger
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
CREATE TABLE [_TEST_MemberDetails] (
[MemberID] int identity (1000,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
[MDid] int NULL UNIQUE,
[MTid] int NULL UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY ([MemberID]),
FOREIGN KEY (MDid) REFERENCES [_TEST_MembershipDetails] ([MDid]) ON DELETE SET NULL
                                                         ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (MTid) REFERENCES [_TEST_MarketingTarget] ([MTid]) ON DELETE SET NULL
                                                        ON UPDATE CASCADE    
);


 CREATE TABLE [_TEST_MarketingTarget] (
 [MTid] int identity (5000,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 [MDOB] date NOT NULL,
 [MSex] char NOT NULL CHECK (MSex IN ('M','F')) DEFAULT 'M',
 PRIMARY KEY ([MTid]),
 );


 CREATE TABLE [_TEST_MembershipDetails] (
 [MDid] int identity (2000,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 [MType] varchar(10) NOT NULL CHECK (MType IN ('Monthly','Quaterly','Yearly')) DEFAULT 'Monthly',
 [JoinDate] Date NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
 [ExpiryDate] Date NULL,
 [MsUpdateDate] Date DEFAULT GETDATE(),
 PRIMARY KEY ([MDid])
 );

 -- SP CODE START HERE
 SET XACT_ABORT ON;
 BEGIN TRY
     BEGIN TRANSACTION
     DECLARE @MTID int = 0, @MDID int = 0

     INSERT INTO _TEST_MarketingTarget ([MDOB], [MSex])
     VALUES ('Jan 1, 2020', 'M')
     SELECT @MTID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

     INSERT INTO [_TEST_MembershipDetails] ([MType], [JoinDate], [ExpiryDate], [MsUpdateDate])
     VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'Jan 1, 2020', DEFAULT)
     SELECT @MDID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

     INSERT INTO [_TEST_MemberDetails] (Mdid, MTid)
     SELECT @MDID, @MTID

     COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT <> 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
go
```